# Using an 'Unknown' value in a MS Access query to return all record values

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access database, with a field called Sex. This field can have 3 values, selected by a lookup:

`Unknown`
`Male`
`Female`

I have a search form, which passes search values to a query.

When you search for `Unknown`, query should return: `Unknown`, `Male`, `Female` (i.e. return all, as the actual sex of the subject could be anything)

When you search for `Male`, query should return: `Unknown`, `Male` (as any `Unknown` sex could actually be a male)

When you search for `Female`, query should return: `Unknown`, `Female`

Is this possible within the Design Query view, or would I need to use SQL?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hardcode the possible values in your query, you can use a simple trick: create a new little table with the matching values that you need.

For example, you can create a new table like the following:

```
SEX_COND - A table with two columns, for the matching values:

V   V_NEW
-   -----
M   M
M   U
F   F
F   U
U   M
U   F
U   U
```

So you can write your simple query with QBE or SQL, by joining the two tables (SEX and SEX_COND) and filtering on the new table column.

With SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE_WITH_SEX_COL
WHERE SEX IN (SELECT V_NEW
              FROM SEX_COND
              WHERE V = 'your_sex_value_to_be_filtered');
```

If you want to use the QBE, you can specify the following condition (where you usually specify a filtering criteria):

```
In (SELECT V_NEW FROM SEX_COND WHERE V = 'M')
```

If you don't want to create a new table, you can use another trick (with the three sex values hardcoded):

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE_WITH_SEX_COL
WHERE SEX IN ('M', 'U') AND 'your_value' = 'M'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE_WITH_SEX_COL
WHERE SEX IN ('F', 'U') AND 'your_value' = 'F'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE_WITH_SEX_COL
WHERE 'your_value' = 'U';
```

When you pass a value to "your_value" variable, only one (out of three) subquery will returns a recordset.

Comment: Is it possible to code that in SQL, rather than making a second table? I have a few other tables I want to do to the same thing with, and don't want to mess of making 10 more tables. Something like this (pseudocode only!)

`WHERE (IF([Forms]![Search_form![Sex])="Male", (tbl_Attributes.Sex)="Male" OR "Unknown")
               ELSEIF([Forms]![Search_form]![Sex])="Female", (tbl_Attributes.Sex)="Female" OR "Unknown") );
             ElSEIF ([Forms]![Search_form]![Sex])="Unknown", (tbl_Attributes.Sex)="Male" OR "Unknown" OR "Female")
ELSE(tbl_Attributes.Sex)="Male" OR "Unknown" OR "Female)`

Comment: I updated my answer with another example, without the additional table that you don't like... :) I hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the addition. 
`SELECT tlk_Ele_Name.[Ele name], tlk_Ele_Name.[ID card color], tlk_Ele_Name.Sex, tlk_Ele_Name.[IDed by], tlk_Ele_Name.[Lobes], tlk_Ele_Name.Tusk_length, tlk_Ele_Name.Tusk_position
FROM tlk_Ele_Name
WHERE tlk_Ele_Name.[Sex] IN (2, 3) AND [Forms]![frm_Search and make IDs]![Sex] = '2'`

This works fine, but when I have the second two iterations below it (for males (1,3) and unknown (1,2,3), I get an error saying EXPECTED: SELECT, DELETE, etc..

Comment: Do you build your query via code (in an Event procedure)? If so, try to assign the selected item in the form ([Forms]![frm_Search and make IDs]![Sex]) to a local variable, build the full SQL statement, and then execute it.